# how to convert private-ip address to public?

Tags: android, networking, ip-address, firewall, nat

(192.168.0.103) this is my private ip address. I want to convert my private address to public. I am running apache-tomcat in my machine to provide service for my android application. Please help me out what i need to do?

Answer (score 2):

I take it that you mean, 'how do I access an internal machine on my subnet externally'.

1. Determine the public IP address of the apache server by visiting a site that will show the public IP address (such as www.whatismyip.com).
2. In any firewalls between external and your apache server, set up port forwarding to the apache server. This will require you to map the inbound connections to your internal server.
3. On the local firewall on the apache server, make sure that inbound connections to the apache server are enabled.
4. Connect from your android device to your apache server using the public IP address from 1 and the port set up during port forwarding in 2.

Note: -

- Be **very** careful about exposing internal devices to the public internet and allowing access into your subnet. Make sure that you server is secured correctly. Consider putting the server in a DMZ.
- Unless you have a static IP address, the public address is likely to change.